# Подключение к ECU автомобиля через OBDII

Tags: java, android, usb, can

Я начинающий Android-разработчик. Хочу написать приложение для чтения ошибок с авто. Пытаюсь прочитать телефоном информацию с авто по USB **без использования** ELM327. Согласно стандарту OBDII, запрос должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
The functional PID query is sent to the vehicle on the CAN bus at ID 7DFh,
using 8 data bytes

0x7DF    0x02 0x01 0x05 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

где 0x7DF - ID запроса;

0x02 - количество байт, которые нужно считать;

0x01 - Сервис;

0X05 - Parameter ID (температура охлаждающей жидкости);

Остальные байты должны игнорироваться.

Здесь я столкнулся с проблемой того, что ID запроса занимает 11 бит и я не могу просто отправить запрос одним массивом.

```
byte diagnosticId = (byte) 0x7DF; // Это неправильно, показано для примера.

byte[] request = {diagnosticId, 0x02, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
```

Для работы по USB я использовал [эту](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android) библиотеку

Подскажите, как я могу отправить запрос такого формата. Может быть нужно переписать библиотеку или как-то упаковать ID запроса, разбив его на 2 байта? Но я не уверен, что он правильно прочитается ECU...

Я находил несколько решений для отправки таких пакетов реализованных на С++. Но там огромное количество кода, которое связано между собой, и я пока хотел бы избежать внедрения нативного кода на этом этапе...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно документации OBD2 (с трудом представляю себе что это) - написано, что идентификатор запроса (11 бит) должен быть упакован в 2-х байтовое слово (16 бит) - в терминах Java это переменная типа `short`, это можно сделать так:

```
short diagnosticId = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[]{0x07, 0xDF}).getShort();
```

Или в байтовых массивах так:

```
byte[] diagnosticId = {0x07, 0xDF};
```

**Update**

Как говорится в некоем [спец форуме](https://community.carloop.io/t/handling-29-bit-extended-format/239/2):

> > When receiving a message with an 11-bit ID, only the lower 11 bits will be filled

Что и подразумевает, что из 16 бит будет заполнены нижние 11 битов. Если идентификатор 29 битовый то тогда заполняются из 32 битов только нижние 29

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло! Не могли бы Вы поделиться ссылкой на документацию, в которой нашли, что идентификатор запроса (11 бит) должен быть упакован в 2-х байтовое слово (16 бит)? Я почему-то не нахожу. Наверное, невнимательно ищу...

Comment: См. апдейт ответа